# file sent to null (empty) by using socket in android studio

Tags: java, android, sockets

Server side code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView infoIp, infoPort;

static final int SocketServerPORT = 8080;
ServerSocket serverSocket;

ServerSocketThread serverSocketThread;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    infoIp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.infoip);
    infoPort = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.infoport);

    infoIp.setText(getIpAddress());

    serverSocketThread = new ServerSocketThread();
    serverSocketThread.start();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    if (serverSocket != null) {
        try {
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private String getIpAddress() {
    String ip = "";
    try {
        Enumeration<NetworkInterface> enumNetworkInterfaces = NetworkInterface
                .getNetworkInterfaces();
        while (enumNetworkInterfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
            NetworkInterface networkInterface = enumNetworkInterfaces
                    .nextElement();
            Enumeration<InetAddress> enumInetAddress = networkInterface
                    .getInetAddresses();
            while (enumInetAddress.hasMoreElements()) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumInetAddress.nextElement();

                if (inetAddress.isSiteLocalAddress()) {
                    ip += "SiteLocalAddress: "
                            + inetAddress.getHostAddress() + "\n";
                }

            }

        }

    } catch (SocketException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        ip += "Something Wrong! " + e.toString() + "\n";
    }

    return ip;
}

public class ServerSocketThread extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Socket socket = null;

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SocketServerPORT);
            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    infoPort.setText("I'm waiting here: "
                            + serverSocket.getLocalPort());
                }});

            while (true) {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                FileTxThread fileTxThread = new FileTxThread(socket);
                fileTxThread.start();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (socket != null) {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

public class FileTxThread extends Thread {
    Socket socket;

    FileTxThread(Socket socket){
        this.socket= socket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        File file = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                "graphs.txt");

        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        BufferedInputStream bis;
        try {
            bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            bis.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
            os.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            os.flush();
            socket.close();

            final String sentMsg = "File sent to: " + socket.getInetAddress();
            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                            sentMsg,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }});

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
}
```

Client Side Code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText editTextAddress;
Button buttonConnect;
TextView textPort;

static final int SocketServerPORT = 8080;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editTextAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.address);
    textPort = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.port);
    textPort.setText("port: " + SocketServerPORT);
    buttonConnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect);

    buttonConnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ClientRxThread clientRxThread =new ClientRxThread(editTextAddress.getText().toString(),SocketServerPORT);
            clientRxThread.start();
        }});
}

private class ClientRxThread extends Thread {
    String dstAddress;
    int dstPort;

    ClientRxThread(String address, int port) {
        dstAddress = address;
        dstPort = port;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Socket socket = null;

        try {
            socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);

            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"graphs.txt");

            byte[] bytes = new byte[8192];
            InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
            int bytesRead = is.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            bos.write(bytes, 0, bytesRead);
            bos.close();
            socket.close();

            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                            "Finished",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }});

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

            final String eMsg = "Something wrong: " + e.getMessage();
            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                            eMsg,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }});

        } finally {
            if(socket != null){
                try {
                    System.out.println("socket not null  "+socket);
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Error shoews in client side :

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2648
>                     Process: com.example.moraya.socketfileserverside1, PID: 30793
>                     java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=8192; regionStart=0; regionLength=-1
>                         at java.util.Arrays.checkOffsetAndCount(Arrays.java:1719)
>                         at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:135)

hi sir, i am trying to transfer file client to server by using socket, but after click on connect button client side application says unfortunately application has stopped and also the empty text file send into the sdcard.

please help me what is the error and how to solve it.

Comment: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=8192; regionStart=0; regionLength=-1 , what is this error, please explain me

Comment: By using above mention code application crashed(stopped) after click on connect button . How to solve this error. please give me solution